# How to get a switch to turn on/off a button on another layer? 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, switch-statement

The question is pretty much in the title.

But i'm trying to make a settings page, where when you press a switch a button becomes visible on another page when the switch is turned on, and hidden and un-functional when the switch is off.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: A different layer is a different view? Well all you need is a reference to the view and have your button which should be toggled exposed as a property.

Comment: I'm new at this, and still new to coding too. So if you could specify a bit more?

And thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: So you don't have code yet but like to know the general way to approach this?

Comment: Yes, i'm learning through doing, as this is the way to approach it from my perspective. :)

Comment: have a look at this blog: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/. Explains the situation quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok a good approach would be to have some kind of model which reflects the current state of your settings. Don't save state in the view!

When you turn that particular switch set the model accordingly.

Now when your other view becomes visible you just read your model and set the visibility depending on what's in the model. To know when a view will appear use a [UIViewController's viewWillAppear](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16).method

Comment: I did not understand that answer, and i dont know if you understand me, but if you look at this picture, would like this switch to hide/unhide that button
http://i.imgur.com/Sw2CM.png

Comment: @Tipsy I understood what you like to achieve, the problem is that I don't know how experienced you are. My answer pointed to a general approach. Since you provided no code nor a specific situation it's kind of hard to be more detailed. How should we proceed?

Comment: I was thinking you could call the switch a public thing, then go to the first viewController and say

`if (switch == ON) secondButton.hidden = NO
Else secondButton.hidden = YES`

http://i.imgur.com/OPI9p.png

Comment: @Tipsy OK, but there are some drawbacks to your solution. Consider saving the state somewhere else(call it model, cause it's just a name). Now you got the data at some place other than your two controllers. This will give you the advantage of initializing your second controller when you need, but not in the moment the first switch is turned. When the 2nd controller comes to life then read the "model" and set the visibility.

Comment: Now i just need the proper way to call the switch a public from a third coding .m?

That would require me linking from the switch to the third coding place and then from the third coding place to the firstViewController?

Comment: @Tipsy that's right. This way you decouple the two heavy controller's from each other. For the beginning make the model a global variable. Then when everything works try a singleton pattern. If you don't like that you can hold the model in a rootViewController or in the appDelegate and pass it down to every class that needs it.